# Slow query when using ORDER BY and LIMIT

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, sql-order-by, limit

I have a very slow query because using ORDER BY. Now i understand why it is slow but i have no idea how i make it faster.

The table got like 21.000 records. (the reason why it is slow)

```
SELECT 
 id_registre, 
 section, 
 numero_naissance, 
 annee_naissance, 
 TYPE, 
 prenom_fr, 
 nom_fr, 
 prenom_ar, 
 nom_ar, 
 date_naissance_equivalent, 
 date_redaction_equivalent
FROM registres
ORDER BY annee_naissance, numero_naissance
LIMIT 20010 , 30
```

I use limit because i use pagination.

This query takes like 119 seconds, which is way too long. if i remove the order by clause, this query takes like 0.92 seconds.

I have indexe on annee_naissance, numero_naissance column.

The type of "annee_naissance" and  "numero_naissance" columns is int(11)

Comment: Have you checked execution plan, time required for sorting the results? Are there any sort overflows for this query? If all these are under limit then I would suggest you to try clustered index on those 2 columns.

Comment: Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE registres`.  In particular, what is the `PRIMARY KEY`?

Answer (score 0):

The best index for this query is a composite index on `registres(annee_naissance, numero_naissance)`.

Note that both columns need to be in the same index.

Comment: Run an `explain` to see if it is using the index.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to force composite index (in case MySQL optimizer choose to use filesort)

```
CREATE INDEX naissance_idx ON registres(annee_naissance, numero_naissance);
```

and then

```
SELECT * 
FROM registres 
FORCE INDEX(naissance_idx) 
ORDER BY annee_naissance, numero_naissance 
LIMIT 20010,30
```

but I am not sure if that can reduce query time from 119s to 1s.

More ORDER BY optimization tips: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: I tested this index, but it is still very slow

Answer (score 0):

I tested the EXPLAIN query

```
EXPLAIN SELECT 
         id_registre, 
         section, 
         numero_naissance, 
         annee_naissance, 
         TYPE, 
         prenom_fr, 
         nom_fr, 
         prenom_ar, 
         nom_ar, 
         date_naissance_equivalent, 
         date_redaction_equivalent
        FROM registres
        ORDER BY annee_naissance, numero_naissance
        LIMIT 20010 , 30
```

and this the result:

[image: Explain query]

Comment: The index is shunned when the number of rows that the index would find is less than something like 20% of the table.

Answer (score 0):

`OFFSET` is slow because the query must find, then discard 200010 rows.

You can make it much faster by "remembering where you left off".  See [my pagination blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination).